# How can I share my screen using WhatsApp on Ubuntu?

Tags: whatsapp

WhatsApp supports screen sharing on its Android app, its iOS app, and its Windows app. It does not seem to support screen sharing on the web app found at https://web.whatsapp.com .

Is there a way to use WhatsApp's screen sharing feature on Ubuntu?

I've noticed that there are multiple unofficial Snap packages of WhatsApp:

```
$ snap search whatsapp
Name                       Version          Publisher        Notes  Summary
whatsapp-linux-app         1.0.0            swe-himel        -      Whatsapp Linux App
whatsapp-app               1.0.1            foksord          -      WhatsApp App
whatsapp-for-linux         1.6.4            nshecan          -      An unofficial WhatsApp desktop application for Linux
whatsapp-4linux            1.1.0            chimekkoo        -      WhatsApp unofficial desktop app for linux
whatsappwebwrapper         1.1.0            user123321123    -      WhatsAppWebWrapper
whatsie                    v4.14.2.c478a7d  keshavnrj✪       -      Feature rich WhatsApp Client for Linux Desktop
kesty-whatsapp             1.2.7            olubunmi708      -      kesty-whatsapp
walc                       0.2.1            cstayyab         -      WALC - unofficial WhatsApp Linux Client
wrapup                     0.1.3            validatedev      -      A Whatsapp client for Linux
whatee                     1.0.0            heliherreradev   -      A simple unofficial WhatsApp desktop client.
...
```

FlatHub also provides multiple WhatsApp packages.

Do any of these Snap or Flatpak packages provide screen sharing support for WhatsApp? Do they work on both X11 and Wayland?

Comment: To share your screen you need to be able to make video calls from Ubuntu. The web page does not allow video or audio calls, only text chats.

Comment: If it's even possible, you could try running the other platforms' apps in Wine or Waydroid

Comment: Why did this question receive downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no.

They're all wrappers around the website. If the website doesn't do it, then these applications won't.

Comment: I've started listening to your podcast, and I love it :)